# Cannot connect to PostgreSQL DB over a Virtual IP (VIP)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, connectivity, network

- I am running a PostgreSQL DB Server v12.16 on an Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine.
- When I attempt to connect to DB directly from host, it WORKS!
- When I attempt to connect to DB via the VIP, it DOESN'T work :(

On attempting to connect to DB via VIP, I get the below error messages. Assume the IP of the VIP to be A

**Command:** `pg_isready --host=A`

**Response:** `A:5432 - no response`

**Command:** `psql -h A -U postgres`

**Response:** `psql: error: server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.`

Question:

Do I need to change any configuration on DB server to make this work? The postgresql.conf file is set to `list_addresses='*'`?

Comment: Look into the PostgreSQL server log. If you see no matching error message, this is a problem in your network configuration.